# WPF listbox copy to clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, clipboard

I am trying to copy a standard WPF listbox selected Item (displayed) text to clipboard on CTRL+C. Is there any simple way to achieve this. If it is something that works for all the listboxes int he app.. that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the answer at http://blogs.gerodev.com/post/Copy-Selected-Items-in-WPF-Listbox-to-Clipboard.aspx. But still looking for an option to add it globally to the app.

Comment: Above link in comment is dead.

Comment: @BenWalker .. well that was an old link. Same solution is provided below by eagleboost

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you're in WPF so you could try the attached behaviours
First you need a class like this:

```
public static class ListBoxBehaviour
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoCopyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoCopy",
        typeof(bool), typeof(ListBoxBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(AutoCopyChanged));

    public static bool GetAutoCopy(DependencyObject obj_)
    {
        return (bool) obj_.GetValue(AutoCopyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoCopy(DependencyObject obj_, bool value_)
    {
        obj_.SetValue(AutoCopyProperty, value_);
    }

    private static void AutoCopyChanged(DependencyObject obj_, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e_)
    {
        var listBox = obj_ as ListBox;
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e_.NewValue)
            {
                ExecutedRoutedEventHandler handler =
                    (sender_, arg_) =>
                    {
                        if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
                        {
                            //Copy what ever your want here
                            Clipboard.SetDataObject(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
                        }
                    };

                var command = new RoutedCommand("Copy", typeof (ListBox));
                command.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.C, ModifierKeys.Control, "Copy"));
                listBox.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(command, handler));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have the XAML like this

```
<ListBox sample:ListBoxBehaviour.AutoCopy="True">
  <ListBox.Items>
    <ListBoxItem Content="a"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="b"/>
  </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Updates: For the simplest case, you can access the text in the below way:

```
private static string GetListBoxItemText(ListBox listBox_, object item_)
{
  var listBoxItem = listBox_.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item_)
                    as ListBoxItem;
  if (listBoxItem != null)
  {
    var textBlock = FindChild<TextBlock>(listBoxItem);
    if (textBlock != null)
    {
      return textBlock.Text;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

GetListBoxItemText(myListbox, myListbox.SelectedItem)
FindChild<T> is a function to find a child of type T of a DependencyObject
```

But just like the ListBoxItem could be bound to object, the ItemTemplate could be different as well, so you can't rely on it in real projects.

Comment: Thanks for this Elegant and almost perfect solution. I guess the only missing part is that, how to detect the content presenter and get the actual displayed text, in case of MVVM architecture, as we will not be binding simple strings, rather objects.

Comment: In lieu of a FindChild function, I used return listBoxItem.Content.ToString(); instead of return textBlock.Text;