# WPF ListView's GridView copy to clipboard

Tags: listview, gridview, mvvm, copy, clipboard

I've a GridView like follow:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Full name" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
```

All I wish is that when pressing **Ctrl + C** all items (or selected items) are copied to the clipboard. Currently it's not. I'm using *WPF 3.0*.

Partially answered by [WPF listbox copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937476/wpf-listbox-copy-to-clipboard) but what I need seem simpler and I guess has also a simpler solution.

PS: This GridView doesn't support built-in column sorting and so on. If you know a better control that's free and support copying feel free to suggest it as a solution.

Comment: I've used the ContextMenu to give a similar functionality without having the Ctrl + C shortcut (as `Command="Copy"` is grayed).

Answer (score 3):

Took me some time to answer this question, so here's how I did it to save someone else time:

Function to copy the data to the clipboard, it also solves the problem of getting the rows in the right order in the resultant string:

```
void copy_selected()
{
    if (listview.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        //where MyType is a custom datatype and the listview is bound to a 
        //List<MyType> called original_list_bound_to_the_listview
        List<MyType> selected = new List<MyType>();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(MyType s in listview.SelectedItems)
            selected.Add(s);
        foreach(MyType s in original_list_bound_to_the_listview)
            if (selected.Contains(s))
                sb.AppendLine(s.ToString());//or whatever format you want
        try
        { 
            System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (COMException)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, unable to copy surveys to the clipboard. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

I still have occasional issues with the a COMException when I copy stuff to the clipboard, hence the try-catch. I seem to have solved this (in a very bad and lazy fashion) by sort of clearing the clipboard, see below.

And to bind this to Ctrl + C

```
void add_copy_handle()
{
    ExecutedRoutedEventHandler handler = (sender_, arg_) => { copy_selected(); };
    var command = new RoutedCommand("Copy", typeof(GridView));
    command.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.C, ModifierKeys.Control, "Copy"));
    listview.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(command, handler));
    try
    { System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, ""); }
    catch (COMException)
    { }
}
```

which is called from:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    add_copy_handle();
}
```

Obviously this is copied a lot from the link above, just simplified but I hope it's useful.